# Meltdown on x86 cpu with pae in 32bit mode

Tags: security, x86, 32-bit

Most modern x86 CPUs implement physical address extension ([pae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)). With that it is possible for the operating system to address up to 64 GBytes of memory while Applications usually can only see and address 4 GBytes of RAM at a time. Even an PAE aware application need to switch the 4 GB Memory window to address more memory.

Could this be used to protect a 32bit-pae operating system kernel from meltdown attacks?

Comment: Yes but the kernel cannot be switched out completely as the entry point of system calls and exceptions/interrupts must be mapped. Doing this on a 4GiB granularity is cumbersome (but doable), using [KPTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_page-table_isolation) is more effective, eventually with large pages. Also, the PAE bit changed semantic with the introduction, years ago, of the IA32e, thus it would be available only to 32-bit systems. Side note: PAE can now map up to 2^52 addresses. I believe having a separate implementation for 32 and 64-bit versions would bee to complex.